# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat is changing the year and month

Tags: php, apache, datetime

I have a function using `DateTime::createFromFormat` that is producing some very odd behavior. It is changing pieces of the parsed string. The timezone is declared with `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`. It is running on Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.4.25. The function is:

```
public function getTimeDiff()
{
    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->start);
    $startDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s.u',$this->start);
    $startTimestamp = $startDateTime -> getTimestamp();
    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($startDateTime);

    \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->stop);
    $stopDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s.u',$this->stop);
    $stopTimestamp = $stopDateTime -> getTimestamp();
   \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($stopDateTime);

    $diffInSeconds = $stopTimestamp - $startTimestamp;

    return $diffInSeconds;
}
```

And the debug info looks like this:

```
string '2014-05-02 08:00:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[426]
  public 'date' => string '2013-12-02 08:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 17:00:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[427]
  public 'date' => string '2013-12-02 17:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 08:30:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[438]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-02 08:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 09:20:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[437]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-02 09:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 09:30:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[437]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-02 09:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 10:20:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-02 10:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 10:30:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[438]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-02 10:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 11:20:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[437]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-02 11:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 11:30:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[437]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-02 11:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 12:20:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-02 12:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 13:30:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[438]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-02 13:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
string '2014-05-02 14:20:00.000' (length=23)
object(DateTime)[437]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-02 14:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Chicago' (length=15)
```

Any idea what is causing the change? I'm hoping it's something obvious that I just can't see for whatever reason.

Comment: You have an error in your format: `Y-m-d H:m:s.u` You're using `m` as both the month and the minutes. Use `i` for minutes.

Comment: And `u` is for microseconds, but it looks like your times only have milliseconds. There's no format code for milliseconds.

Comment: Ha! I knew I was overlooking something simple. Thanks phpisuber01! If you want to list it as an answer I will mark it selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided in comments and reiterated here for an easy find.

> You have an error in your format: Y-m-d H:m:s.u You're using m as both the month and the minutes. Use i for minutes. -phpisuber01